# stack problem: want to check if expression is correctly parenthesized and balancing and matching

Tags: c, string, stack

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int stack[20];
int top=-1;
void push(int x)
{
    stack[top]=x;
    top++;
}

int pop()
{
    return stack[top--];
}

int checkmatching(char a[])
{
    int i=0,j=top;
    int count = top;
    while(i+1<=count)
    {
        if(strcmp(a[i],a[j])==0)
        {
            pop(a[i]);
            pop(a[j]);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        else return -1;
    }
   return 1;
}

int main()
{
    char exp[20],i,m;
    printf("give the expression: ");
    scanf("%s", &exp);
    for(i=0;exp[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        push(exp[i]);
    }
    m=checkmatching(exp);
    if(m>0)
        printf("matched");
    else printf("no match");
  return 0;
}
```

I have a warning for this code:

> |21|warning: passing argument 1 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast
>   |43|note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'char'
>   |21|warning: passing argument 2 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast|
>   |43|note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'char'|

Comment: `strcmp(a[i],a[j])` is wrong simply use i`f(a[i] == a[j])`. `strcmp` is for `string` not for `char`.

Comment: `warning: xxx makes pointer from integer without a cast ` is almost always an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing two `char`  with `strcmp` (string compare)

Just compare the chars directly:

```
int checkmatching(char a[])
{
    int i=0,j=top;
    int count = top;
    while(i+1<=count)
    {
        if((a[i] == a[j]))
        {
            pop(a[i]);
            pop(a[j]);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        else return -1;
    }
   return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`strcmp()` compares strings, and you're passing it chars (notice that a is a string) you can compare chars with regular `==`

from a brief look you're also trying to use pop with an argument, and I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve.

are you trying to check if the expiration is a palindrome? why using a stack for that? clear your question please

Answer (score 1):

Don't use strcmp(), use if().

```
If(a[i] == a[j])
{
     pop(a[i]);
     pop(a[j]);
     i++;
     j--;
}
```